# How can I "break up" a long running server side function in a Meteor app?

Tags: node.js, meteor

I have, as part of a meteor application, a server side that gets POST messages of information to feed to the web client via inserts/updates to a Collection.  So far so good.  However, sometimes these updates can be rather large (50K records a go, every 5 seconds).  I was having a hard time keeping up to this until I started using batch-insert package and then low-level batch.find.update() and batch.execute() from Mongo.

However, there is still a good amount of processing going on even with 50K records (it does some calculations, analytics, etc).  I would LOVE to be able to "thread" that logic so the main event loop can continue along.  However, I am not sure there is a real easy way to create "real" threads for this within Meteor.  So baring that, I would like to know the best / proper way of at least "batching" the work so that every N (say 1K or so) records I can release the event loop back to process other events (like some client side DDP messages and the like).  Then do another 1K records, etc. until however many records as I need are done.

I am THINKING the solution lies within using Fibers/Futures -- which appear to be the Meteor way -- but I am not positive that is correct or the low level ideas like "setTimeout()" and/or "setImmediate()" are more appropriate.

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

Meteor is not a one size fits all tool. I think you should decouple your meteor application from your batch processing. Set up a separate meteor instance, or better yet set up a pure node.js server to handle these requests and batch processes. It would look like this:

- Create a node.js instance that connects to the same mongo database using the mongodb plugin (https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb).
- Use express if you're using node.js to handle the post requests (https://www.npmjs.com/package/express).
- Do the batch processing/inserts/updates in this instance.

The updates in mongo will be reflected in meteor very quickly. I had a similar situation and used a node server to do some batch data collection and then pass it into a cassandra database. I then used pig latin to run some batch operations on that data, and then inserted it into mongo. My meteor application would reactively display the new data pretty much instantaneously.

Comment: I had actually thought of that -- but this is supposed to be a "simple' lightweight standalone application -- the data is actually thrown away after being looked at, etc. It's actually all wrapped up in a C#/.NET desktop app that runs under Windows.. so I am hoping I could get it with just the single "node" application since that data really isn't persistent (new db each run).  However, it may come down to your solution. :) Hmm... I also presume your approach would require me to figure out how to get the REPLSET and OPLOG tailing to work in this "dynamic" temp. environment.. ??

Answer (score 0):

You can call `this.unblock()` inside a server method to allow the code to run in the background, and immediately return from the method. See example below.

```
Meteor.methods({
  longMethod: function() {
    this.unblock();
    Meteor._sleepForMs(1000 * 60 * 60);
  }
});
```

Comment: This is an intriguing answer -- but not sure it will help my case in that, unlike your example -- that does a _sleepForMs() -- which effectively relinquishes control anyway -- I have a pretty CPU intensive function that will still suck up the thread that is running and not allow other things to happen. Hence the idea to do a batch of work -- release -- come back and do another batch, etc. Or maybe I'm missing something with unblock(). :)

Comment: What unblock does is allow the method to return before it finishes processing whatever it does after the .unblock() call. If you do not use unblock, the method will wait until your heavy operation finishes before returning it's final result to the client. As for you process being very heavy and taking up all available server resources, there's not much I can help with, sorry :)